# How to set RecurrenceRowset = true when creating a view programmatically

Tags: calendar, recurring-events, spview

I'm trying to create 3 different calendar views which I will use as overlays to represent the same set of data but color coded differently based on the calendar view shown.

Im using the object model to create the views as follows:

```
SPViewCollection allviews = list.Views;

string query = "bla bla ...";

view = allviews.Add("MyView", viewFields, query, 100, true, false, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Calendar, false);
```

Now the problem I have is that when this view is created, the 'RecurrenceRowset' property is not set and the Calendar view shows empty.

If I change the viewtype as in:

```
view = allviews.Add("MyView", viewFields, query, 100, true, false, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Recurrence, false);
```

The view displays all the items, however I need a calendar view.
If I look at the default Calender view that is created in a calendar list the view xml clearly shows the recurrence property set to TRUE

```
<View Name="{F24E3A4A-67D8-4EEB-BB6A-6ABF7772DAB7}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="CALENDAR" TabularView="FALSE" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" DisplayName="Calendar" Url="/sites/IC/Lists/Task Calendar/calendar.aspx" Level="1" />
```

In the object model however, if you create a view, the 'RecurrenceRowset' property is READ-ONLY. How do I set it???

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/9b6da8da-65da-4b5d-83cb-1abb8d6a55df) is a bit of a hack but it should work. Change the flag via the webpart.

```
      using (var webPartManager = newView.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(newView.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
      {
        foreach (WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts)
        {
          if (webPart is IListWebPart)
          {
            var listWebPart = (IListWebPart)webPart;
            if ((listWebPart.ViewFlags | SPViewFlags.RecurrenceRowset) != SPViewFlags.RecurrenceRowset)
            {
              listWebPart.ViewFlags = listWebPart.ViewFlags | SPViewFlags.RecurrenceRowset;
              webPartManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```